# Xamarin.Forms style BarBackgroundColor transparent

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, transparent, navigationbar

My goal is to have a transparent navigationbar for Android & iOS in Xamarin.Forms. Problem is that the hexa color for value not works (#FFFFFF00 e.g.)

Here is my code of my general stylesheet:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="[insert value for transparent]" />
</Style>
```

Comment: you can refer this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67315/set-transparent-background-color-of-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

You can Also define Color Name :

```
 <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
       <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
 </Style>
```

If still not working then you have to change it in Android project style.xml page.